# How to make a UIButton Delete Itself

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

So this is my code:

```
for (int x = 1; x < 100; x++) {
        int randomX = arc4random() %280;
        int randomY = arc4random() %500;

        UIButton *myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        [myButton setTitle:string forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        myButton.frame = CGRectMake(randomX, randomY, 40.0, 40.0);
        [myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonUp) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        [self.view addSubview:myButton];
```

How do I make the buttons delete themselves when let go?

Thanks,
Bogdan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the selector to

```
@selector(buttonUp:)
```

Then in your method definition

```
- (void)buttonUp:(UIButton*)sender
```

add

```
[sender removeFromSuperview]
```

Comment: Thank you soo much! I tried doing the same thing but without the ":". Thanks!